# LENOVO Z2 PLUS VOLTE ISSUE with jio

Tags: mobile-data, lenovo, apn

In my lenovo Z2 Plus handset with jio ,  currently jio volte stopped working  . 
I was not able to make calls , but internet is working sometimes and sometimes not .

I restarted the device many times but no luck ?

Is there any solution to this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check, if the SIM card on which VoLTE service to be used is placed in SIM 1 slot.
Only SIM 1 slot is enabled for HD(VoLTE) voice capability as per my observation.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution  ,

In some regions and cities Reliance puts limits on the speed so if it doesn't work for you that means in your area Jio speed is limited by Reliance itself does not matter what you do so keep that in mind. So folks here is the settings. Go to Settings -> Cellular Networks -> Advanced Options -> Access Points Names -> Internet In APN you have to change the following, rest all remains the same:- 1) APN Protocol: ipv4/v6 2) APN Roaming: ipv4/v6 3) Bearer: LTE Save, restart and enjoy..